# How not to not to convert certain symbols with htmlentities()?

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities

How can I 'ask' `htmlentities()` not to convert certain symbols? For instance,

php,

```
<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('fonts.css'),ENT_QUOTES);?>
```

fonts.css,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRoman';
    src: url('chunkfive-webfont.eot'); /* EOT file for IE */
    src: local('☺'), url('chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

result,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRoman';
    src: url('chunkfive-webfont.eot'); /* EOT file for IE */
    src: local('â�º'), url('chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

I want to keep '☺' as it is but not to convert it into 'â�º'.

Is it possible?

Comment: `htmlentities` does not work like that, so the problem is somewhere else. Perhaps your css file is encoded in utf-8 but you are displaying it as HTML in a single-byte encoding?

Comment: Thanks Jon. Probably I am displaying the css as HTML in a single-byte encoding... But now it seems to work fine with mario's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the third parameter of [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities). It specifies the charset:

```
<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('fonts.css'),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");?>
```

This avoids the smiley to be converted into Latin-1 byte equivalents. (Which is what it looks like.)